# Count records grouped by years between 2 dates in R with 0 records in certain years

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe with ID, start and end dates, and some other events occuring on specific dates. I wish to calculate the number of events occuring per year for each ID from the start and end dates, including 0 events on certain years. I can get number of events per year between start and end but I cannot figure out how to expand the dataframe to include any years with 0 events.

```
example<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                    start=c("1998-05-01","1998-05-01","1998-05-01","1998-05-01",
                            "2020-07-20","2020-07-20",
                            "1977-12-23","1977-12-23","1977-12-23","1977-12-23",
                            "1977-12-23","1977-12-23","1977-12-23","1977-12-23"),
                    end=c("2007-05-01","2007-05-01","2007-05-01","2007-05-01",
                           "2021-07-20","2021-07-20",
                           "1990-12-23","1990-12-23","1990-12-23","1990-12-23",
                           "1990-12-23","1990-12-23","1990-12-23","1990-12-23"),
                    date_event=c("1998-06-05","2000-01-01","2002-11-30","2006-12-21",
                                 "2020-12-20","2020-12-25",
                                 "1978-02-23","1982-05-05","1983-06-20","1988-11-29",
                                 "1988-12-29","1990-01-01","1990-12-15","1990-12-15"))
> example
       ID      start        end date_event
    1   1 1998-05-01 2007-05-01 1998-06-05
    2   1 1998-05-01 2007-05-01 2000-01-01
    3   1 1998-05-01 2007-05-01 2002-11-30
    4   1 1998-05-01 2007-05-01 2006-12-21
    5   2 2020-07-20 2021-07-20 2020-12-20
    6   2 2020-07-20 2021-07-20 2020-12-25
    7   3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1978-02-23
    8   3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1982-05-05
    9   3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1983-06-20
    10  3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1988-11-29
    11  3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1988-12-29
    12  3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1990-01-01
    13  3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1990-12-15
    14  3 1977-12-23 1990-12-23 1990-12-15
```

I tried:

```
example[,year:=lubridate::year(date_event)]
summary<-example[,.(contacts=.N),by=c("ID","year","start","end")]
```

which gave me

```
>         summary
    ID year      start        end contacts
 1:  1 1998 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 2:  1 2000 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 3:  1 2002 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 4:  1 2006 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 5:  2 2020 2020-07-20 2021-07-20        2
 6:  3 1978 1977-12-23 1990-12-23        1
 7:  3 1982 1977-12-23 1990-12-23        1
 8:  3 1983 1977-12-23 1990-12-23        1
 9:  3 1988 1977-12-23 1990-12-23        2
10:  3 1990 1977-12-23 1990-12-23        3
```

but I would like

```
>         summary
    ID year      start        end contacts
 1:  1 1998 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 1:  1 1999 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        0
 2:  1 2000 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 1:  1 2001 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        0 
 3:  1 2002 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 1:  1 2003 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        0
 1:  1 2004 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        0
 1:  1 2005 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        0
 4:  1 2006 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        1
 1:  1 2007 1998-05-01 2007-05-01        0
```

etc..

I have also tried dplyr but this code gives me an error.

```
summary<-example %>% 
  transmute(ID, year_start=year(start), year_end=year(end),
            year=year(date_event),event=1) %>% 
  count(ID,event,year=factor(year,levels=unique(year_start:year_end)))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

example <- example %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.Date(.x)), 
    year = year(date_event), 
    start = min(date_event), end = max(date_event), .by = ID) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), .by = c(ID, year, start, end))

example %>%
  reframe(year = min(year):max(year), .by = c(ID, start, end)) %>%
  left_join(example) %>%
  replace_na(list(n = 0))

   ID      start        end year n
1   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 1998 1
2   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 1999 0
3   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2000 1
4   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2001 0
5   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2002 1
6   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2003 0
7   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2004 0
8   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2005 0
9   1 1998-06-05 2006-12-21 2006 1
10  2 2020-12-20 2020-12-25 2020 2
11  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1978 1
12  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1979 0
13  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1980 0
14  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1981 0
15  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1982 1
16  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1983 1
17  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1984 0
18  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1985 0
19  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1986 0
20  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1987 0
21  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1988 2
22  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1989 0
23  3 1978-02-23 1990-12-15 1990 3
```

Comment: thank you! although I would probably use year=year(example$start):year(example$end) since all date_events fall between the start and end years and I want a count of events for every year from start to end.

Comment: @Hong I wasn't sure about the events which occur in 1978 (it looks like the events aren't arranged in order..

Comment: ah I realised that my question wasn't clear - I'm trying to get the number of events per year in each "ID" group. How would you make the tibble by ID group?

Comment: Thanks to Mark's suggestions I have come up with my final code. The only difference is that I used reframe year(start):year(end) rather than min(year):max(year), because the first and last events are not necessarily in the start and end year, but rather they occur within the time period between start and end.